# How to find the array with the most elements in it within a group of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, element

I'm trying to find out how to find the array with the most elements in it within a group of arrays.

I am interested in a fast and easy way to retrieve it. I have tried it out myself, but I'm a beginner and need help. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to use null, but I am at a pretty beginner level. I just want to know if there is a specific method or I should contains...

Comment: I answered your question below, but it sounds like you should read a good Java tutorial (I recommend the Oracle docs), try to implement this problem, then repost the code you tried. By saying you "have tried to use null", it sounds like you have not covered the basics of the language (and this sounds like a practice interview problem -- though a basic one -- that you would need to be more comfortable with Java to answer.

Comment: @JavaPerson There's no specific method for this. When you say group of arrays, do you mean array of arrays or `Collection` (e.g. `List`) of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the length of an array in constant time. So loop through each array and check it's length. Take the max of these lengths. This would be O(n) where n is the number of arrays. Assuming the group of arrays is stored in an array (but this implementation would work with a few tweaks for any Java collection, since a foreach loop is versatile):

```
// (skipping method signature for brevity)

int maxLength = 0;
for (Object[] objArray : arrayOfArrays) {
     maxLength = Math.max(objArray.length, maxLength);
}
return maxLength
```

You could also store the arrays in order of their sizes if this result was a priority in your program (or better: Store an object that has a reference to the longest array and its length. And if you increase the length of another array, and that array is longer than the current longest-array reference, you update the reference.)

Comment: You're probably going to need to show him an example.

Comment: Added an example. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @NicholasFolk You mean Math.max

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo. This code will tell you the length of the array with most non-null elements.

```
public class Arrayed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[] biggest = null;
        int max = -1;

        Object[][] _2d_arr = { { null, "1", "5", "6" },
                { "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8" }, { null, null, "1" } };

        for (Object[] _1d_arr : _2d_arr) {
            int count = 0;

            // count non null objects
            for (Object x : _1d_arr) {
                if (x != null) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }

            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                biggest = _1d_arr;
            }

        }

        if (biggest != null) {
            System.out.println("Biggest array has length..." + biggest.length);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If I use `count = count++;` instead of `count = count +1 ` my code fails. I wonder why.

Comment: you should change it to only count++; count=count++; does not make sense. It means you are assigned count = count and then incrementing the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxLength = 0;
for (Object[] objArray : arrayOfArrays) {
maxLength = objArray.length > maxLength ? objArray.length : maxLength;
}
return maxLength
```